# How to create different views for different user roles?

Tags: plugins, user-roles, user-access

I am creating a website where highschoolers can go do a bunch of tests to see what are their best abilities, what work would suit them etc. The tests work. I have created a registration form whit RegistrationMagic plugin. The tests are saved, I want to create 4 roles for this site, the student, teacher , pincipal and admin of site(me). You can only do the tests if you are logged in. Lets say the student role can do the tests and save them for later seeing. Now for the teacher I want her to be able to see her students test results. How would I go about doing that?

Hopefully i explained myself clear enough, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a programming solution I can follow up in the comments with examples, but I think the best "plug and play" solution would be an existing solution like Learndash(https://www.learndash.com/) or Sensei (https://woocommerce.com/products/sensei/).

These have different roles, quizzes with grading, and other features that you may find useful. Here are some additional resources that may help:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcSTaMhZi64
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJM-v5MR5vM

Hope this helps!